# dust particle detection on a glass plate sample with yolo v8

Tags: python, yolov8

I am trying to detect some particles on a sample that is small, my sample size is 5000X3000 pixels and my particle size is only 80X80 pixels.
Should I divide the input image into smaller images and then annotate or directly proceed with bigger image annotation?
If I train my model with the smaller image, then will it show the same detection rate for the original size of the sample?